# want other person to receive credit for their answer

Tags: support, voting, accepted-answer

Someone answered my math question, re [zero area of a graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362951/zero-area-of-a-graph).  I think their answer is brilliant and should be given points.  However, after I "accepted" the answer, I found that my reputation was insufficient to personally reward the answer.  I did leave a corresponding comment to the answer.

What is the standard way for someone to request that the site-admins reward such an answer?

Comment: The standard way is to accept their answer. 15 points will be then awarded to the answer-er.

Comment: This has nothing to do with my diamond and should not be interpreted as precedent, but as it happens I think it's a neat answer too, so I put a reward bounty on it for you.

Answer (score 6):

By accepting the answer, which you already did, you give the green checkmark and 15 points to the user.

The mark signals that your question is answered and there is also some overall reward for the user that answered.

It is true that at the moment you cannot influence the score of the post. But soon once you have a few more points you will also be able to upvote the answer, which will increase its score by 1 and award 10 additional points to the user.

To answer your question directly: there is no such way and this is not done,  it is not even possible. (As a user I could upvote the post, but I cannot do anything specific as a moderator.) But every asker can accept one answer.